# Rasch Analysis: comparison of the distribution person location estimates across independent samples

Tags: item-response-theory, rasch

I hardly understand Rasch analysis (and this isn't my goal) but I need to clarify the following questions before delving deeper:

Does it make any sense within the framework of Rasch analysis (and related concepts) to compare the distribution of person location estimates across independent samples?

Example 1:

We have test data from class A and test data from class B. We conducted Rasch analyses on both data sets and assigned a the value of the person location estimate to each pupil. We look at the distribution of these values. Does this allow us to make a statement like:

- The pupils in class A were on average more "proficient" than the pupils in class B.

Example 2:

Let's say we repeat the test in the same class at two time points (but we cannot match the anonymized results). Do summary statistics/test of the person location estimates allow us to make a statement like:

- The pupils proficiency increased/decreased on average between t0 and T1.

I would be very grateful if somebody could enlighten me.

Note: Each data set is analysed separately.

Comment: Person location scores are ability estimates? You conducted analysis on both sets combined, or separately?

Comment: @JeremyMiles Each data set is analysed separately. It is not guaranteed the original data is available when conducting the comparison. But the mean, median, sd etc. of the score should be known.